# Webpack - Best way to update HTML to include latest [hashed] bundles

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, browser-cache, webpack-2

I'm using webpack to generate hashed bundle filenames.

Assuming I'm using static HTML, CSS & JS, what is the best way to automatically update `index.html` to point to the latest bundles?

For example,

**update:**

```
<script src="e8e839c3a189c25de178.app.js"></script>
<script src="c353591725524074032b.vendor.js"></script>
```

**to:**

```
<script src="d6cba2f2e2fb3f9d98aa.app.js"></script>
<script src="c353591725524074032b.vendor.js"></script> // no change
```

automatically everytime a new bundle version is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazingly, this is what the [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) is for.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function(env) {
    return {
        entry: {
            main: './src/index.js',
            vendor: 'moment'
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[chunkhash].[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
            }),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                tempate: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html')
            })
        ]
    }
};
```

This generates an `index.html` in the `dist` directory that includes the `script`'s in the correct order.

[youtube example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIiMrLcc3hE)